# Dax issue: The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value

Tags: powerbi, dax

Trying to get my code to work:

```
`DTAT Filters = 
VAR NA = {
    ("Country", NAMEOF('FactDTAT'[Country_Name]), 0),
    ("Director", NAMEOF('FactDTAT'[Field_Ops_Director]), 1),
    ("Manager", NAMEOF('FactDTAT'[Field_Ops_Manager]), 2),
    ("Sub-region", NAMEOF('FactDTAT'[Field_ops_region]), 3)
}
    VAR LATAM = {
    ("SubRegion",NAMEOF('FactDTAT'[sub_region4_name]), 0) }


RETURN IF(SELECTEDVALUE(FactVolume[sub_region1_name])="North America",
CALCULATETABLE(NA),
CALCULATETABLE(LATAM))`
```

I am getting "The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value." Any thoghts?

My goal is to create a "dynamic" filter when I select LATAM region I want to show a set of filters, and when I click on North America I want to show the other set, So Latam filters only got subregion at the moment, but I will add more, if I can make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Measures cannot return tables/rows, only a scalar (single) value.</s>
Apologies for assuming it was a Measure and not a Calculated Table.

`IF` & `SWITCH` can only return a scalar value.
You can try this as a workaround:

```
DTAT Filters = 
  VAR NA = {
    ("Country", NAMEOF('FactDTAT'[Country_Name]), 0),
    ("Director", NAMEOF('FactDTAT'[Field_Ops_Director]), 1),
    ("Manager", NAMEOF('FactDTAT'[Field_Ops_Manager]), 2),
    ("Sub-region", NAMEOF('FactDTAT'[Field_ops_region]), 3)
  }
  VAR LATAM = {
    ("SubRegion",NAMEOF('FactDTAT'[sub_region4_name]), 0) 
  }

  VAR isNA = SELECTEDVALUE(FactVolume[sub_region1_name]) = "North America"

  RETURN UNION(
    FILTER( NA, isNA ),
    FILTER( LATAM, NOT(isNA) )
  )
```

**Important**
Please note that Calculated Tables are calculated at refresh time and **not at runtime**. So above you will always get `LATAM` since `SELECTEDVALUE` is meaningless at refresh time.

Feel free to post a new question with what you are trying to do with slicers/filters as there are various solutions/options to what you might be looking for. Alternatively, I believe this post will be what you are looking for: [Dynamic filtering with Field parameters in Power BI!](https://data-mozart.com/dynamic-filtering-with-field-parameters-in-power-bi/)

Comment: This is not a meassure, this is creating another table. If I just use: DTAT Filters = {
    ("Country", NAMEOF('FactDTAT'[Country_Name]), 0),
    ("Director", NAMEOF('FactDTAT'[Field_Ops_Director]), 1),
    ("Manager", NAMEOF('FactDTAT'[Field_Ops_Manager]), 2),
    ("Sub-region", NAMEOF('FactDTAT'[Field_ops_region]), 3)
} it creates a table with 3 columns: DTAT Filters,DTAT Filters  Fields and DTAT Filters  Order

Comment: Updated answer above, apologies for assuming it was a Measure.

Comment: This solution works for the original question, but you are write, it only works at refresh time if 1 filter is applied or the other. Thanks anyway, I will try to put what I want to accomplish, as per the link the code that I have works like that already, I just wanted to go a step further and have all my options change when I select 1 region or the other.

Comment: Look further down in that article. Add a custom column to your Field Parameter table, with "North America", and "LATAM" for the rows you want. Use the custom column for your first slicer, and the second will take care of itself.